# What are the Asterisk and Plus sigs on diskutil?

Tags: macos, terminal, disk-utility

I am starting to use diskutil for scripts managing my removable media and sorts; however, there is a few cryptic symbols I cannot figure out, I googled to no avail, but still not finding the true meaning of the **asterisk** and **plus** symbols next to the sizes.

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         250.7 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.7 GB   disk1
                              Physical Store disk0s2
1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     217.1 GB   disk1s1
2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 172.2 MB   disk1s2
3:                APFS Volume Recovery                529.0 MB   disk1s3
4:                APFS Volume VM                      7.5 GB     disk1s4
5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            11.3 GB    disk1s5
```

Anyone shedding some light will be endlessly appreciated!

Comment: This is just a guess, but I think it indicates that it indicates that it's a container, i.e. the size includes the following sizes (rather than adding to them). For example, in the disk0 entry, it should be read as 251.0 GB = 314.6 MB + 250.7 GB (plus any free space), rather than 251.0 GB + 314.6 MB + 250.7 GB. I don't know what `*` vs `+` indicates. BTW, for scripting purposes, it's probably better to use the `-plist` output format (and maybe use [`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/8/PlistBuddy/) to parse it).

Comment: Thanks for your input @GordonDavisson! You have become a teacher for me on all things Apple, answering many of my questions. I will keep in mind PlistBuddy for such tasks, I actually remember we had a long talk about it when I was trying to create some daemons to monitor stuff on my computer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The asterisk (`*`) indicates a physical disk and the plus sign (`+`) indicates a virtual disk. Some types of virtual disks are listed below.

- `disk image` which includes mounted `.iso`, `.dmg`, `.sparseimage` files and `.sparsebundle` folders.
- `synthesized` as used in APFS containers.
- `virtual` as used in core storage logical volumes.

With latest versions of macOS, `diskutil list` species the type of disk using actual words (such as given above). With older legacy versions of OS X, such words where not given in the output from the `diskutil list` command. In such cases, users needed to rely on the `*` and `+` characters to distinguish between physical and virtual disks.

For example, below is the output from `diskutil list disk1` using macOS High Sierra on a USB drive.

```
/dev/disk1 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *17.2 GB   disk1
   1:                  Apple_HFS Install Yosemite        17.2 GB   disk1s1
```

Below is the output from `diskutil list disk1` using OS X Yosemite on the same drive. The string  `(external, physical):` does not appear, while the character `*` does appear.

```
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *17.2 GB   disk1
   1:                  Apple_HFS Install Yosemite        17.2 GB   disk1s1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @David for such detailed and complete answer! May I ask one last Q?
What would `Physical Store disk0s2`mean in the virtual disk? (on my output example). Thanks!

Comment: From the High Sierra man page for diskutil, "Physical Store" is defined as the following: *"An APFS Physical Store is a disk which is imported into (that is, which backs, indeed defines) an APFS Container. An APFS Container can import more than one Physical Store, e.g. for Fusion-style Containers."* The disk referred to in that definition can be physical or virtual. For example, a physical store could be a partition from a disk image. As I explained in my answer, a disk image (which is just a file or folder) is a virtual disk.

Comment: In your case, `disk1` identifies a container (that is virtual) which  resides in the partition identified as `disk0s2`. This partition (physical store) exists as a slice of the `disk0` drive, which is physical. I suppose everything that is virtual in the end has to reside on media that is physical.

Comment: Thanks again @David for the amazing and very detailed explanation! It's amazingly useful for newbies (and not so newbies), it helps understand concepts in a very easy yet precise way!